# How can I align multi-line expressions at the equal sign?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, expression

I'm looking for a solution in annotating a ggplot2-figure with multilines in R, that are aligned at the equal sign like in LaTeX' equation using the "&-symbol" within in align{}-environment  :

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
M &= 0.00\\
SD &= 1.00
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I found a solution for multiline expression combining text with variable values.
Here is my reproducable example:

```
example.data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000,0,1))
line1 = as.character(format(round(mean(example.data$x), digits = 2), nsmall = 2)) # Mean
line2 = as.character(format(round(sd(example.data$x), digits = 2), nsmall = 2)) # SD

#Plot a histogram 
ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(
        data = example.data,
        aes(x = x),
        binwidth = 1)+
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    annotate(
        geom = "text",
        x=2,
        y = 300,
        label = paste('atop(italic(M) == "',line1,'",italic(SD) == \"',line2,'")',sep=''),
        parse = TRUE)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to split up your multiline expression into parts. In the code below I use a vector of length 4 and use `vjust` to split into two lines and `hjust` for the horizontal alignment at the equal sign:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(
    data = example.data,
    aes(x = x),
    binwidth = 1
  ) +
  xlim(-3, 3) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 2,
    y = 300,
    # Align first line at the bottom, second line at the top.
    # ... and add some padding
    vjust = c(0, 0, 1, 1) - .1 * c(1, 1, -1, -1),
    # Align LHS on the right, RHS on the left
    hjust = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
    label = c(
      'italic(M) == ""', line1,
      'italic(SD) == ""', line2
    ),
    parse = TRUE
  )
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_bin()`).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`).
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions, @stefan! Actually, I'm using the ggplot approahc within a function to automate data visualization. Is your solution a "manual only" solution, or could I use your approach in an automatic way? However, despite the question of automatisation, your approach seems to mo magically and fantastic!

Another question (raising from your suolution): Is it possible to align the rows not only at the equal sign, but also at the decimal sign (.) in addition to the equal sign?

Comment: In general the approach should be scalable to be used in a function. In that case however, I would switch to `geom="label"` which via the `label.padding` argument allows to set the padding in absolute units (whereas vjust will depend on the scale of the data) , i.e. pt or mm. (And to get rid of the box use fill = NA and label.size = 0). Basically the only remaining tricky part is setting the x-y position. To this end, switching to annotation_custom might be worthwhile as it allows to place the label in relative coordinates.

Comment: Concerning the alignment at the decimal mark. In general also possible. As the worst case this might require to convert the numbers to strings first and splitting into two parts, left and right of the decimal point.